# Cucumber run only one feature file and ignore the rest

Tags: java, cucumber, extent

I had created two features file but there is one feature file being execute and the second feture file is not get executed. Why is like this?

```
@CucumberOptions(
        features = {"src/test/resources/Features/"},
        glue = {"com.nicholas.StepsDef"},
        plugin = {"pretty", "com.nicholas.Manager.GlobalHooksManager",
                "com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter:"}

)
```

There are two features file located at src/test/resources/Features/. One is login and another is add product. The add product is never executed. Please help. A billion thanks for your help.

[image]

Why is like this?
Source Code: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zgXCxSzoQj70FEVCWQf65n8iQWIcfPxm/view?usp=sharing

[image]

Comment: I found out the root cause is related to extent report. When i comment out th extent report, it will run two features file.